# ICQ through Google talk in pidgin

Tags: pidgin

Can you tell me a way to run icq through google talk on pidgin? I want to have a history in one place.

Answer (score 3):

First, you might want to write down a list of names and ICQ numbers. If you use aliases in Pidgin, those aren't going to show up through Google Talk and you can be left wondering who's who.

Click Accounts > Manage Accounts and disable all accounts except the Google Talk one.

Click Tools > Plugins, scroll down and tick the XMPP Service Discovery plugin.

Next, click Accounts > XMPP Service Discovery > XMPP Service Discovery. Make sure your Google Talk account is selected and click Browse. Put in the name of a server that runs externally accessible transports. I use jabber.hot-chilli.net. There's a list at http://coccinella.im/servers/servers.html.

Click the ICQ transport and click Register. Type in your ICQ number and password.

You will receive an invite from icq.jabber.hot-chilli.net (if you chose that transport server). Accept it.

You will then receive a *flood* of invites, one from each of your ICQ contacts. Those people aren't actually re-inviting you, it's just the mechanism the transport uses to get those people onto your Google Talk contact list. Accept them all.

You now have all your ICQ contacts on your Google Talk list. I recommend logging in to Gmail and using the contact manager there to rename people and merge those icqnumber@icq.jabber.hot-chilli.net addresses with your existing contacts rather than renaming them in Pidgin so changes appear on every device you log in from.

Don't re-enable your ICQ account in Pidgin. You're now using it through Google Talk instead of connecting to the ICQ server directly. You will need to re-enable any accounts that you didn't register a transport for.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find an ICQ->jabber transport, and [set things up to use it](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2006-05-02-n79.html)